# Keras network with multiple inputs taking long time to train

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

### I have two models:

- one with 32 inputs, 32 outputs, 5000 parameters
- one with 4 channels of 8 inputs and 32 outputs. 4000 parameters

The four channel version is taking an inordinately long time to train. I can train my first model for 50 epochs, while the second hasn't even finished one.
It takes about 1 second for a prediction. Is there anyway I can speed up my ntwk?

### Edit:

Here are the summaries for both models:

## Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to

input_53 (InputLayer)            (None, 2, 8)          0

---

input_54 (InputLayer)            (None, 2, 8)          0

---

input_55 (InputLayer)            (None, 2, 8)          0

---

input_56 (InputLayer)            (None, 2, 8)          0

---

conv1d_176 (Conv1D)              (None, 2, 8)          72          input_53[0][0]

---

conv1d_179 (Conv1D)              (None, 2, 8)          72          input_54[0][0]

---

conv1d_182 (Conv1D)              (None, 2, 8)          72          input_55[0][0]

---

conv1d_185 (Conv1D)              (None, 2, 8)          72          input_56[0][0]

---

conv1d_177 (Conv1D)              (None, 2, 4)          36          conv1d_176[0][0]

---

conv1d_180 (Conv1D)              (None, 2, 4)          36          conv1d_179[0][0]

---

conv1d_183 (Conv1D)              (None, 2, 4)          36          conv1d_182[0][0]

---

conv1d_186 (Conv1D)              (None, 2, 4)          36          conv1d_185[0][0]

---

merge_6 (Merge)                  (None, 2, 16)         0           conv1d_177[0][0]
                                                                   conv1d_180[0][0]
                                                                   conv1d_183[0][0]
                                                                   conv1d_186[0][0]

---

conv1d_188 (Conv1D)              (None, 2, 32)         544         merge_6[0][0]

---

conv1d_189 (Conv1D)              (None, 2, 16)         528         conv1d_188[0][0]

---

conv1d_190 (Conv1D)              (None, 2, 32)         544         conv1d_189[0][0]

---

flatten_10 (Flatten)             (None, 64)            0           conv1d_190[0][0]

## dense_10 (Dense)                 (None, 32)            2080        flatten_10[0][0]

Total params: 4,128
Trainable params: 4,128
Non-trainable params: 0

---

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

conv1d_90 (Conv1D)           (None, 2, 32)             1056

---

conv1d_91 (Conv1D)           (None, 2, 16)             528

---

conv1d_92 (Conv1D)           (None, 2, 8)              136

---

conv1d_93 (Conv1D)           (None, 2, 16)             144

---

conv1d_94 (Conv1D)           (None, 2, 32)             544

---

flatten_42 (Flatten)         (None, 64)                0

---

## dense_42 (Dense)             (None, 32)                2080

Total params: 4,488
Trainable params: 4,488
Non-trainable params: 0

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you print out a `model.summary()` for both models?

Comment: Added the summary for both